# How to use NodeJs logo on Windows Terminal?

Tags: node.js, icons, windows-terminal

I recently downloaded Windows Terminal from the Windows Store and I'm setting it up. Unfortunately node is not automatically available, so I added it manually, it was localed at "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe". But the icon is missing. Does anyone know how to find it, and also have any other tips on finding icons for other shells if needed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the icons to most shells at https://devicon.dev/ and download them from their github repo at https://github.com/devicons/devicon

Because these icons are in svg format, you will need to use an svg viewer like inkscape (which is free), to export them as a png at your required resolution.

Then you can use the icons in the windows terminal.